# ¿Consultar una fecha anterior equivalente a 10 días?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, carbon

Estoy trabajando con laravel y utilizando eloquent para hacer consultas sobre mi base de datos SQL, Necesito hacer una consulta para obtener los registros de una tabla. Dicha consulta solo debe de traer los datos que se crearon hace 10 días y que no esta validado.

```
Modelo::where('Validacion', '!=', 1)
->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
->get();
```

No se como calcular la fecha actual menos 10 días.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías restarle los días de esta manera:

```
Modelo::where('Validacion', '!=', 1)
  ->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->add(-10, 'day')->format('Y-m-d'))
  ->get();
```

O de esta otra:

```
Modelo::where('Validacion', '!=', 1)
  ->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->subDays(10)->format('Y-m-d'))
  ->get();
```

También te dejo el link a la documentación: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Si he leído la documentación pero me parece muy confusa

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me sirvió al 100

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo esta variación que es un poco mas correcta y os explico el porque

```
Modelo::where('Validacion', '<>', 1)
  ->whereDate('created_at', now()->subDays(10))
  ->get();
```

- La negacion (!=) aunque es aceptada, es de PHP y no de MySql, por lo que es mas correcto "<>".
- En los "where", el operador "=" ya esta implícito, por lo que no es necesario.
- "Carbon::now()" tiene un Helper llamado "now()".
- El format no es necesario en las query dado    que el gestor(Eloquent) usa objetos(Carbon/Date), no cadena de texto.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi te dejo este modelo de query para que la acoples a tus necesidades

```
$ventasAnteriores = DB::table('ventas')
                ->select(DB::raw('SUM(venta) as anteriores'))
                ->where('created_at', 'like', '%'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('d'. '-10 days')).'%')
                ->get();
```

Yo de esa manera lo hice y me ha funcionado para consultar las ventas de hace 10 dias